# How to create a Loop to see how much you scrolled in Flutter?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, counter

How can you create a loop where the scrolled amount in pixels get displayed using `ScrollPosition`
Let's say the user scrolls up and down through the screen where he does the following,

Assume that the view is 10,000 pixels

Goes around halfway in the screen, Come backs to the top and goes somewhere around 3/4 of the view. Can you use `ScrollPosition` to get create a loop to get the total distance scrolled in pixels, so a number will display as, 5000+5000+7500 = 17500 pixels. Any ideas would be appreciated.
Code:

```
body: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  
                  new ListView.separated(
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
                    itemCount: 10,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/avatar.jpg"),
                      ),
                      title: Text("List Index is $index"),
                    ),

                  ),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a state

```
double totalScrolled = 0;
```

in your widget definition and wrap your `ListView` in a `NotificationListener<ScrollUpdateNotification>`

```
NotificationListener<ScrollUpdateNotification>(
  child: ListView(
  ),
  onNotification: (notif) { 
    totalScrolled +=notif.scrollDelta.abs();
 
  },
),
```

then simply add the absolute value of the `scrollDelta` to your `totalScrolled`

Comment: I added the code I was writing, but I can't add the NotificationListener because when I add it it goes as a new tab. and if I create a container inside ListView it gives me too many positional arguments error